# Sort a list of objects containing list each with orderby

Tags: c#, list, sorting

I have this object:

```
public class humanInfo
{
    public string m_Name { get;set; }

    public List<HumanAttributes> m_ListHumanAttributes { get; set;}
}
```

I want to sort this list based on the `Age` attribute which is located in the list of attributes for each humans.

```
humanList = humanList.OrderBy(/*How am I gonna do this?*/);
```

I have tried to attain all the items using `x => x.m_ListHumanAttributes.All()`, for example, but I am a bit clueless as to how I might proceed. Anyone has a good idea?

**EDIT**

Here's an idea how the `HumanAttributes` class might work:

```
public class HumanAttributes
{
    public int m_HumanAttributesID {get;set;}

    public Sex m_HumanAttributeSex {get;set;}

    public int m_HumanAge {get;set;}

    public decimal m_HumanHeight {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: can we take a look at `HumanAttributes`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming HumanAttributes has Name and Value properties:

```
humanList.OrderBy(h=>h.ListHumanAttributes.First(a=>a.Name=="Age").Value);
```

Comment: +1 I would use `DefaultOrFirst`, giving room / opportunity for dealing with humans with no "Age" attribute defined

Comment: Say I would like to sort them by name in alphabetical order, how could I proceed?

Comment: @HerveS , pretty much the same. If value holds the reference to string, they will be sorted alphabetically.

Comment: @AdrianCarneiro Small thing, but it's [`FirstOrDefault`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340482.aspx), not `DefaultOrFirst`

Comment: @VisualMelon No idea why I wrote wrong an expression that I write day in day out. Sigh, I guess I'm not *that* multitasking... :)